# test cases of a form filling workflow

Tags: testing, functional-testing, livecycle

a software called livecycle has got forms with different fields in which data is to be filled. on submitting the form the data is stored in the mysql database. the user fills the form partially at his level and there is an assign to field . the user assigns this form to another user. using the workflow of the livecycle software the other user gets the form and completely fills it.

i am writing test cases and can think of following test case

1. test case of a valid data form filling and checking all valid scenario's that should happen when everything valid is chosen.
2. test case when out of range values are entered in the form to see if the system crashes on submitting the form.

please suggest any other test cases i can write ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also want to test that the data the first user entered into the form is the same for the next user in the workflow, as well as testing for cases like a worflow being assigned to an invalid user or even the same user.  Also situations where the form is not fully filled out when it should, or assigning a completed form to a different user.

For more testing you could look at a tool to measure your tests' code coverage and work toward complete branch coverage of your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the test of OS compatibility